# Console.Write(i) in each for or Console.write(Stringbuilder) at the end which one is better

Tags: c#, console

`Console.Write(i)` in each `for` or `Console.Write(StringBuilder)` at the end: Which one is better?

I have two functions, the first one prints within the for loop and the other one is printing at the end.

```
public static void checkmethod1(int value, Checkevent text)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch2.Start();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    switch (text)
    {
        case Checkevent.odd:
            for (int i = 1; i <= value; i = i + 2)
            {
                builder.Append(i).Append(" ");
            }
            break;

        case Checkevent.even:
            for (int i = 2; i <= value; i = i + 2)
            {
                builder.Append(i).Append(" ");
            }
            break;
    }
    stopwatch2.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(builder);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", stopwatch2.Elapsed);

}
```

Function 2:

```
public static void checkmethod3(int value, Checkevent text)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch2.Start();

    switch (text)
    {
        case Checkevent.odd:
            for (int i = 1; i <= value; i = i + 2)
            {
                Console.Write(i);
            }
            break;
        case Checkevent.even:
            for (int i = 2; i <= value; i = i + 2)
            {
                Console.Write(i);
            }
            break;
    }
    stopwatch2.Stop();
    Console.Write("{0}", stopwatch2.Elapsed);
}
```

Comment: Both look syntactically correct and equally useless... Please define "better" criteria so one can actually judge functions based on your criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular scenario I will prefer `StringBuilder` as The loop is not taking significant time that could change the user experience. The StringBuilder in general require less memory and you will get better performance. As you each modification in string new `string` object is create but that is not the case with `StringBuilder`.

The first method executed the `Console.Write` only *once* but the second on will execute it the *times* `for` loop iterates. This will make the second one slow.

If you want to show user the text in console when you want user to see text as it appear like you are showing log to view the process flow then showing it once (with `StringBuilder`) may not give user chance to read it. In that case you would be write log as it is generated using `Console.Write(string)`.

Deciding when to use `string` and when to use `StringBuilder` could become easy when you understand how both work. Their one of important behavior is given as under.

[Using the StringBuilder Class in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The String object is immutable. Every time you use one of the methods
>   in the System.String class, you create a new string object in memory,
>   which requires a new allocation of space for that new object. In
>   situations where you need to perform repeated modifications to a
>   string, the overhead associated with creating a new String object can
>   be costly. The System.Text.StringBuilder class can be used when you
>   want to modify a string without creating a new object. For example,
>   using the StringBuilder class can boost performance when concatenating
>   many strings together in a loop.

**Edit**

I test the above two method with three values 100, 10000 and 100000 and machine used has following specs

```
Operating System: Windows 7 Enterprise and CPU
Processor: Intel(R) Core (TM) i5-3570 CPU @ 3.40 GHz 3.40 GHz
Installed memory (RAM): 8.00 GB
System Type: 64 bit Operating System
```

*Value 100*

> Time *with* StringBuilder        00:00:00.0000184
>   Time *without* StringBuilder     00:00:00.0037037

*Value 10000*

> Time *with* StringBuilder        00:00:00.0013233
>   Time *without* StringBuilder     00:00:00.2970272

*Value 100000*

> Time *with* StringBuilder        00:00:00.0133015
>   Time *without* StringBuilder     00:00:02.5853375

In the first method where you used the `StringBuilder` the `Console.Write` is executed only once but in other case it is executed as many times as the loop iterations. This makes the second one slow. *Comparing StringBuilder with string concatenation is not applicable here.*

Comment: Using a `StringBuilder` in this scenario is redundant and will actually cause more memory usage than without.

Comment: Thankyou sir, i confused because i using the unit test to try and stringbuilder get the better time but my teacher say use the other one instead

Comment: @NattananYodsrimongkol if measure something else altogether you can get any time you want, but to really compare something you'd better compare thigs that produce the same result. One measurement includes console output another does not - so there is good reason why one that measures less operations will give better time.

Comment: Using a string builder (or *anything* really) to store the output will obviously require more memory than not storing anything and printing it out directly. So that argument for StringBuilder is moot, and comparing it to string concatenation is helpful in general but also not relevant here. The reason why the string builder example is faster here is because printing to the console is in general ridiculously slow.

Comment: I totally agree with you @poke and I have same opinion.

Comment: If you want to test apples to apples, you need to write to `TextWriter.Null`. As @poke said, console output is horribly slow.